# React-Native List not scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

Problem is listview is not scrolling. I tried many styles but I cant find the way. I using React-Native  0.39.2 . I tried on Android Devices

```
    /**
     * Sample React Native App
     * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
     * @flow
     */
```

`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, TextInput
} from 'react-native';
//import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { Button,CheckBox} from 'react-native-elements'
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'



export default class Kpss extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
  render() {
      const list = [
          {
              name: 'Amy Farha',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice President'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          }, {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },

          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },
          {
              name: 'Chris Jackson',
              avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
              subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
          },


      ];
    return (
        <View style = {styles.maincontainer}>
          <List>
              {
                  list.map((l, i) => (
                      <ListItem 
                          roundAvatar
                          avatar={{uri:l.avatar_url}}
                          key={i}
                          title={l.name}
                      />
                  ))
              }
          </List>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    maincontainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        paddingTop:20,
        paddingBottom:0,
        flex:1

    },



});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Kpss', () => Kpss);

</pre>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to wrap your `List` inside a `ScrollView` to enable scrolling:

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

...

<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView>
    <List>
      ...
    </List>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove style from view and put style for listview:-

```
 <View>
          <List containerStyle={{height:deviceheight,width:devicewidth}}>
              {
                  list.map((l, i) => (
                      <ListItem 
                          roundAvatar
                          avatar={{uri:l.avatar_url}}
                          key={i}
                          title={l.name}
                      />
                  ))
              }
          </List>
        </View>
```

Comment: i think you should use RN listview inside <List> of react-native-elements

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the ScrollView In Inside a View, make the ScrolView your View and your ListItem Inside your ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap each List.Item inside View and TouchableWithoutFeedback